# track gridview percentage completed for completion bar

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, aspxgridview

I'd like to do a javascript completion bar for my gridview.  Does anyone know how to track the progress of a gridview, can it be determined upon runtime how many iterations will be required and where the iterations are at any given time?  I suppose I could do a count query prior to launching the gridview, but I'd still need to know what iteration i'm at to show the progress in asp using c# code behind.
Thanks,
John

Comment: Can you post a code sample to make it easier for others to help with the solution? Or add other details such as what version of .net.

Comment: What does the "progress of the gridview" mean?

Comment: "progress of gridview" = as the gridview loads each row of data it is 1% more completed.  I'd like to know if there is a way to maybe "count" each row of data as the gridview builds prior to it displaying it's completed results.  I could post a standard gridview as code, but I don't see how that would help anyone understand the question.  Thanks.

Comment: Found it... simple solution!  Almost embarrassing. 1st, query the database for total records that match the gridview's select statement, use this as my "completed" value then iterate over the gridview as it's being loaded using JQuery $("#GridViewname tr").each(function () {
         change fill percentage of my div
                globalvar_counter += 1;
            });